# How can i allow users to save videos which are streamed in webview

Tags: android, webview, streaming, download

I have an app which is using android webview .i am able to stream video in webview .i want know how can i allow users to to save videos automatically in thier internal storage  which they stream in webview on website ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the webview itself. You may have to read the video stream and save it yourself.

Comment: How can i read video stream from indirect url ??

Comment: I don't know if you can do it with a webview. You might try reading the html code and finding out the url.

Answer (score 0):

Most videos streaming to a browser (PC or mobile) will not allow download as the owner of the video may not want to allow it be saved and copied etc.

Simple http progressive download may allow you to save the video in a regular browser by simply right clicking on it.

DRM protected video will generally use a video pipeline (a sort of 'path' through your device) that does not allow an application of any kind access the raw video - this is again is to avoid people making unauthorised copies.

If you think the video in your case is allowed to be copied then you may find it easier to write some functionality to act as the streaming client and save the file locally. You could also pass the received stream along to the media player or to a webview if you wanted to play the file in parallel to saving it.